# docker-compose does not start postgres

Tags: django, postgresql, docker-compose

I m creating a docker-compose config for an django app, the Dockerfile builds successfully but when I compose them up, django return an issue -- cannot connect to postgres.

I run docker-compose run web bash, found redis and posgres both cannot be connected.

My docker-compose.yml file

```
web:
 build: .
  ports:
    - "8000:8000"
environment:
  - 'DATABASE_HOST=db'
  - 'DATABASE_NAME=mydb'
  - 'DATABASE_USER=root'
  - 'DATABASE_PASSWORD=root'
links:
  - db
db:
  image: postgres:9.1
```

when running sudo docker-compose up i got the following error.

```
web_1 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 175, in  get_new_connection

web_1 |     connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
web_1 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 164, in connect
web_1 |     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
web_1 | django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
web_1 |     Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
web_1 |     TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
web_1 | could not connect to server: Connection refused
web_1 |     Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
web_1 |     TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Comment: Do you have anything in your Django settings to use those environment variables to define the database?

Comment: my django settings are: `DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'NAME': 'aiotadb',
            'USER': 'root',
            'PASSWORD': 'root',
            'HOST': 'db',
            'PORT': '5432',
        }
    }`

Comment: also tried by changing `'HOST':'localhost'` in settings file and changing `'DATABASE_HOST=localhost'` in docker-compose.yml .still facing same issue.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're bothering to set those values in docker-compose.yml, since you aren't using them anywhere; you've hard-coded the settings. That error message is clearly showing that it is trying to access `localhost`, not `db`, though, so you should check that you really do have `'HOST': 'db'`.

Answer (score 2):

I also built a clustering with `docker-compose`, it probably will help you and answer your problem (here is the [repo](https://github.com/nirgn975/Angular2-Django-cluster)). You can see the [docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/nirgn975/Angular2-Django-cluster/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) file, and the `django` [settings](https://github.com/nirgn975/Angular2-Django-cluster/blob/master/server/config/settings.py#L76L81) file (I marked the lines you need).

You can also clone this repo and get `django`, `angular2`, `postgresql`, and `nginx` containers, all link together already.

Comment: Thanks @Nir I have tried these also,but still the error is same that *Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting*.I have tried docker using sqlite3 and it worked as a charm.

Comment: @AshishK. notice my docker-compose.yml file, my `server` (django) `depends_on` database. It means that `server` container will always wait for `database` container and spin up after it, and not before. Also, upload your `settings.py` file, notice the `'HOST': 'database'` and`'PORT': 5432` in mine (I think that is your problem. your host should be the name of the database container).

Comment: Thanks.Found the issue.Running successfully now.

Comment: port 5432 is not able to listen anything :)

Answer (score 0):

You are linking your web container with the postgres container but you are not defining database name, password and user.

```
  web:
   build: .
   ports:
    - "8000:8000"
   links:
    - db
  db:
    restart: always
    image: postgres:9.1
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - pgvolume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=root
      - POSTGRES_DB= aiotadb
      - POSTGRES_USER=root
   data:
    restart: always
    image: postgres:9.1
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/postgresql
    command: tail -f /dev/null
```

Also, if you already define your database options in your settings file, you don't need to declare it as env variables in web container.

Answer (score 0):

```
version: '3'
services:
  basicproject:
    build: .
    container_name: basicproject-container
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"

  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.4
    ports:
    - "5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=test
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=testing
      - POSTGRES_DB=test_db
```

Answer (score 0):

Add dependency in your 'web' service like below:

```
depends_on:
  - db
```